# Display returned value from Class method to Form

Tags: c#, .net

In `Form GroupExmStart` I am calling `Foo method` from Question class  and storing all Questions in `var questions` and passing it to `int Quiz method`,how can I store this `question` in `string[]` so that i can Display My questions using `DisplayQuestions()`,I tried to convert it into string using `string[] ab=questions.ToArray();` but it is not working , Is that conversion is not possible or Where i am going wrong ?

Form GroupExmStart

```
public partial class GroupExmStart : Form
    {        

        public GroupExmStart(string GroupName, string DurationID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.GrpID=GroupName;
            TopiID=db.GetTopicIDForGroup(GrpID);

            Question qsn = new Question();
            string[] conf = db.GetConfiguration(Convert.ToInt16(DurationID)).Split('|');
             var questions = qsn.Foo(TopiID, conf);
            int z = Quiz(questions);
            int count = 0;

            timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt16(conf[1]) * 1000;          
             timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();


        }

        int Quiz(List<Question> questions)
        {                   
             var str = questions.ToArray();
             foreach (var item in str)//I am not getting how do i do it Getting `item as namespaceName.Question`
                {                    
                }                
            return 0;

        }
private void DisplayQuestion(string id, string Q, string OP1, string OP2, string OP3, string OP4)
        {
            label5.Text = Q; 
            radioButton12.Text = OP4;
            radioButton11.Text = OP4;
            radioButton10.Text = OP4;           
            radioButton9.Text = OP4;
        }
      }        
   }
```

Class Question

```
public class Question
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
        public string Option3 { get; set; }
        public string Option4 { get; set; }

        public string AnswerOption { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }
        Random _random = new Random();
         public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions(string topicId, int marks)
        {            
            string sql = "select QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions where TopicID IN(" +
                         topicId + ") and Marks=" + marks;
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,acccon);
            var rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rs != null)
            {
                while (rs.Read())
                {
                    yield return
                        new Question
                        {
                            Id = rs[0].ToString() + "~",
                            Text = rs[1].ToString() + "~",
                            Option1 = rs[2].ToString() + "~",
                            Option2 = rs[3].ToString() + "~",
                            Option3 = rs[4].ToString() + "~",
                            Option4 = rs[5].ToString() + "~",
                            AnswerOption = rs[6].ToString() + "~",
                            Marks = marks
                        };
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Question> Foo(string TopicId, string[] conf)
        {
            var totQsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[0]); 
            var mark1qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[3]); //this variable contains number of question to be display of mark 1
            var mark2qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[4]);
            var mark3qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[5]);
            var mark4qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[6]);

            var mark1questionSet = GetQuestions(TopicId, 1).ToList();
            var mark2questionSet = GetQuestions(TopicId, 2).ToList();

            var finalQuestions = new List<Question>();

            for (int i = 0; i < mark1qsn; i++)
            {
                var setIndex = _random.Next(mark1questionSet.Count);
                finalQuestions.Add(mark1questionSet[setIndex]);
                mark1questionSet.RemoveAt(setIndex);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mark2qsn; i++)
            {
                var setIndex = _random.Next(mark2questionSet.Count);
                finalQuestions.Add(mark2questionSet[setIndex]);
                mark2questionSet.RemoveAt(setIndex);
            }

            return finalQuestions;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get List data from class to Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108209/how-to-get-list-data-from-class-to-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Quiz(List<Question> questions)
{                   

    foreach (Question question in questions)
    {     
        // do something with question  
        // question.Id, question.Text etc.. can access from here             
    }                
    return 0;

}
```

if you need to display the question you better override the ToString method of Question class as below

```
public class Question
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // you can change this as you wish 
        return string.Formt("Id:{0}, Text :{1}", Id, Text);
    }
```

then you can try below

```
int Quiz(List<Question> questions)
{                   

    foreach (Question question in questions)
    {     
        MessageBox.Show(question.ToString());            
    }                
    return 0;

}
```

Or you can use existing method as below with few modifications

```
int Quiz(List<Question> questions)
{                   
    foreach (Question question in questions)
    {     
        DisplayQuestion(question);            
    }                
    return 0;
}
private void DisplayQuestion(Question question)
{
    label5.Text = question.Text; 
    radioButton12.Text = question.Option1;
    radioButton11.Text = question.Option2;
    radioButton10.Text = question.Option3;           
    radioButton9.Text = question.Option4;
}
```

Comment: I tried That before also when i am trying To display`MessageBox.Show(question.ToString());` to know what i am getting in `question` than i am just Getting this in messageBox `namespaceName.Question`. How can i get each question values so that I can Display them using `DisplayQuestion method ` in my code

Comment: And you can change the `DisplayQuestion` method to receive the `Question` object, instead of breaking all those arguments.

Comment: @Oberdan Nunes Can You please show It in code How to change `DisplayQuestion` method so that i don't need to break those arguments

Comment: @Durga, this is because the Object.ToString() (base class) implementation return the object type name, in order to create an "custom" object representation with string, you can Override the ToString() method, just like `astander` did in the other answer. But I think it'll be better to pass the Question object.

Comment: @Durga `question` is class and u r converting it to string..! try its property like `question.Test`, `question.Id`... as   @Damith mention in answer

Comment: See the last version of @Damith answer. It's exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
var str = questions.ToArray();
```

returns an array of type Question

```
Question[]
```

and not an array of type string.

You will have to create an overload for Question to output to string what you need.

Something like

```
public class Question
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
    ....
```

This should allow you to do something like

```
foreach (var item in str)
{
    string itemText = item.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    string _que = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in questions)
    {
        _que =Convert.toString(item.Text);      
    }                
    return 0;
```

Since `Question` is class and `Text` is one of its property so u can access it by its object.